Ubuntu 24.04 Asus vivobook 16 doesn't wake up after suspension
Issue
Whenever the laptop enters a suspended state, triggered by either closing the lid or the screen going black after a period of inactivity, it becomes unresponsive. This means that pressing keys or the power button doesn't elicit any response. Consequently, I'm always forced to hold down the power button to shut it down and then reboot it.
Specifications

Laptop: ASUS VivoBook 16 M1605XA-MB089
CPU:     AMD Ryzen 9 7940HS
Graphics card:   AMD Radeon 780M
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS noble
Swap partition size is 18GB (my laptop has 16GB RAM)

Outputs that might be helpful to solve the issue
(partial) sudo dmidecode
BIOS Information
Vendor: American Megatrends International, LLC.
Version: M1605XA.305
Release Date: 06/07/2023
Address: 0xF0000
Runtime Size: 64 kB
ROM Size: 32 MB
Characteristics:
    PCI is supported
    BIOS is upgradeable
    BIOS shadowing is allowed
    Boot from CD is supported
    Selectable boot is supported
    BIOS ROM is socketed
    EDD is supported
    ACPI is supported
    Smart battery is supported
    BIOS boot specification is supported
    Targeted content distribution is supported
    UEFI is supported
BIOS Revision: 5.29

System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop M1605XA_M1605XA
    Version: 1.0       
    Serial Number: RBN0CV11M759485
    UUID: 28e1833d-de14-3b47-98f0-78c1e393675b
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number:  
    Family: Vivobook

sudo dmesg | grep -i tpm
[    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0x919e8000 ACPI 2.0=0x919e8014 TPMFinalLog=0x96a15000 SMBIOS=0x9aa14000 SMBIOS 3.0=0x9aa13000 MEMATTR=0x86df2018 ESRT=0x881fa818 MOKvar=0x9a9df000 INITRD=0x853c1698 RNG=0x91983018 TPMEventLog=0x84ea7018 
[    0.004168] ACPI: TPM2 0x00000000919BA000 000044 (v05 _ASUS_ Notebook 00000001 AMI  00000000)
[    0.004214] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0x919ba000-0x919ba043]
[    1.019461] systemd[1]: systemd 255.4-1ubuntu8 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[    1.143086] systemd[1]: systemd-pcrextend.socket - TPM2 PCR Extension (Varlink) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=measured-uki).
[    1.153719] systemd[1]: systemd-pcrmachine.service - TPM2 PCR Machine ID Measurement was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=measured-uki).
[    1.154301] systemd[1]: systemd-tpm2-setup-early.service - TPM2 SRK Setup (Early) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=measured-uki).
[    1.176878] systemd[1]: systemd-tpm2-setup.service - TPM2 SRK Setup was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=measured-uki).

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e8
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e9
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f7
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7902
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9B1 (DRAM-less) (rev 02)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Phoenix1 (rev c1)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 19h (Model 74h) CCP/PSP 3.0 Device
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b9
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ba
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 63)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
04:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
04:00.1 Signal processing controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] AMD IPU Device
05:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c0
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c1

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1d57:fa60 Xenta 2.4G Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3579 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa23 Areson Technology Corp 2.4G Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 322e:2012 BillionPixels USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-5minutes'
May 05 22:08:07 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 systemd-logind[945]: The system will suspend now!
May 05 22:08:07 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1714936087.132:247): pid=927 uid=101 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.14" mask="receive" pid=4846 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=945 peer_label="unconfined"
                                                  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=101 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
May 05 22:08:07 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 ModemManager[1089]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
May 05 22:08:07 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1714936087.1336] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May 05 22:08:07 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1714936087.1352] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
May 05 22:08:08 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 systemd[1]: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.
May 05 22:08:08 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
May 05 22:08:08 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 systemd-sleep[12445]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
May 05 22:08:08 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
-- Boot 6215cc9455944dd189e9a99b8974bcfd --
May 05 22:09:02 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend
May 05 22:09:02 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 kernel: nvme 0000:02:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
May 05 22:09:12 vivobook16-m1605xa-mb089 gnome-shell[2357]: Gio.UnixInputStream has been moved to a separate platform-specific library. Please update your code to use GioUnix.InputStream instead.
                                                            0 inhibit() ["resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/loginManager.js":209:8]
                                                            1 InterpretGeneratorResume() ["self-hosted":1461:33]
                                                            2 AsyncFunctionNext() ["self-hosted":852:26]
                                                            3 anonymous() ["resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js":21:19]

If you need some more info, hit me up in comments section. Thanks in advance!

I tried an earlier kernel like 5.15.0-105 generic and it works fine, but if I use default for 24.04LTE 6.8.0-31 generic it wont restore... bug?
